# How to reach Goa from Delhi without any money

Tags: india, money, hitchhiking, new-delhi, goa-india

I am planning to go to Goa. The only catch is I have no money.

How can I manage to do this? Taking lifts from trucks comes to mind but I have no idea how to go about it?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, this question is a priori off-topic because this website is not a travel agent. Constructing an itinerary is considered off-topic. However, you can ask whether it is possible/easy/in the culture to hitch-hike on cars, trucks or even planes between Delhi and Goa. Anyway, given the distance, it will probably take a long time (and therefore you require more than just transportation), unless you "hitch-hike" on a plane.

Comment: @pnuts why only sikh? I am confused..

Comment: Do the usual, find a gas station at the beginning of the road and ask people who are heading to Goa if they do not mind giving you a lift, that's the only way to be sure.

Comment: I have to admit, my very first reaction to reading this one is "stick your hand out, make a fist, and lift your thumb into the air." And "it helps to be a woman."

Comment: @Vince When you want to travel for free, I'm pretty sure travel agents can't help you either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's get realistic, even if you do whatever other people may say, humans need food and a place to sleep, so absolute free travel is impossible, unless you walk (using your own energy), beg (ask for a lift) or steal (travel without ticket in a train and pretend to have no money to any ticket checking staff, which is highly highly discouraged).

Having said, and considering the total distance of travel to be 4300 kilometres (up and down) that let me try to get as close to that as possible.  There is a train called Goa Express (Indian Railway Train No. 12780 at the time of writing), a comfortable sleeping accommodation on this train would just cost you Rs. 780 ($13), this would ensure that you get two full night's sleep (cant compare that to any hotel around the world),  up and down you would actually pay just $26 on this.

Lets get even more frugal, if you travel by the un-reserved compartment in this train which should cost you Rs. 440 one way, this way you are assured of safety at night however no meaningful sleep is possible, this would be approximately Rs. 880 i.e. $15 for this.

If you want to demonstrate some kind of a world record for this, you can actually try to combine multiple passenger trains to reach the destination, which would involve hardships like dragging any luggage (why don't you sell the luggage to get some money, huh) and extremely tightly packed compartments involving fights (both verbal and physical) to obtain a right to sit (forget sleep). A legal travel for the entire distance on a passenger train would be about Rs. 250 ($4) and hence two way travel would be Rs. 500 i.e. $8, it would be actually tough getting a passenger train ticket for this distance as the staff may argue that there are no direct trains which you have to solve by probably showing a full schedule of your travel (if this question was not hypothetical).

Answer (score 2):

I've read a report at russian-language travel forum from a guy, who hitch-hiked through almost all india, so it seems to be the only option you have

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE, this is not bad as a first answer, but it would be much better if you have some references there (a link to the report?)

Comment: another trip: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Autostop-Polska-Indie/207781805955172

Comment: Thanks for welcoming, the problem is that I can't find that report. Althought there are some other posts with info in russian (but more short, can't find other complete reports) like http://www.auto72.ru/news/news60714.html

Answer (score 0):

I have hitch-hiked from Mumbai to Pathankot, so from my experience -

1. Train travel is easier. You might try your luck without a ticket in a general compartment if you really have no money. But a Goa - NDLS general ticket would cost just around Rs 460.
2. Hitch-hiking is absolutely possible in the day. Look for commercial vehicles - goods carrying jeeps, vans and tempos. Just stick your hand out - and don't tell anyone your final destination initially, just say you need to get to the next town on the highway. Once in the vehicle, strike up a conversation and see if they are going further along your route.
3. At night, hitch-hiking options decrease. Truck drivers are your only bet.